# How to tell if non-scalar key exists in Python dictionary

Tags: python

I tried to use 'in' and has_key(), but these don't appear to work if the key is not a single value:

```
 >>> aarr["x","y","z"]=1
 >>> aarr["x","y","z"]
 1
 >>> if "x","y","z" in aarr:
   File "<stdin>", line 1
     if "x","y","z" in aarr:
           ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
 >>> aarr.has_key("x","y","z")
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>', line 1, in <module>
 TypeError: has_key() takes exactly one argument (3 given)
```

It also doesn't work to try `aarr.has_key(["x","y","z"])` or if `["x","y","z"] in aarr:` in both cases complaining about `unhashable type: 'list'`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are creating a *tuple* when using commas in a expression.

Use a tuple to test:

```
if ("x","y","z") in aarr:
```

You could also have looked at `.keys()` to learn this:

```
>>> aarr = {}
>>> aarr["x","y","z"]=1
>>> if ("x","y","z") in aarr:
...     print 'success!'
... 
success!
>>> aarr.keys()
[('x', 'y', 'z')]
>>> aarr.keys()[0]
('x', 'y', 'z')
```